# Can I add code snippet for JSON in Visual Studio(not Visual Studio Code)?

Tags: visual-studio

First of all，this question is talking about  Visual Studio，not Visual Studio Code！

I want add some code snippet for json file，but in Visual Studio Document，I find there is only 9 types Languages supported. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/code-snippets-schema-reference?view=vs-2022#attributes)

So is there any method to add code snippets without the 9 languages? I also find extensions in market but I don't find the solve.

Thanks for a lot.

Comment: I have the same question.

Comment: @WillHuang  I solved this problem by Resharper->Templates Explorer->Live Templates->Global,and set filename filter in Select Scopes->All->In files matching